# array for loop syntax

Tags: php

If I have:

```
$data = array(
  'id01' => array(
    'firstName' => 'Eric',
    'lastName' => 'Smith',
  ),
  'id02' => array(
    'firstName' => 'John',
    'lastName' => 'Turner',
  ),
);

foreach ( $data as $key){
    print "$key[firstName]<br>";
    echo $key[0];
}
```

The `$key[0]` part is not working...basically i'm trying to output id01, then id02, basically the id part of the array that the forloop is processing...

Any ideas on the correct syntax?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `$key[firstName]` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is

```
foreach ($data as $key => $val){
    print "$val[firstName]<br>"; //changed to $val
    echo $key; //prints id01, id02
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no key for `0` , just first and last name - you need to do this

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value)
{
    echo "Key is " . $key . ", value of firstName 
          is " . $value["firstName"] . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
foreach ( $data as $key=>$value){
    print "$value[firstName]<br>";
    echo $key.'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach ( $data as $key=>$value)
```